# When should I run `react-native start`?

Tags: react-native

Just getting started with React-Native (for the non-CRNA/Expo case) and it's not clear to me after reading the [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) or [Understanding the CLI](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/understanding-cli.html) when it's appropriate to run `react-native start`

`react-native start --help` simply says `starts the webserver`.  Running `react-native run-ios` also starts the same server except it also actually runs it in the simulator.

**Question:** When is it appropriate to run `react-native start` vs. just running the simulators directly (i.e. `react-native run-ios`)?

Answer (score 25):

`react-native start` is same as `npm start` and like you said it's to start the react packager/server.

I have found myself in situations where I had to stop and start the server explicitly using `npm start`.

To start up a project, you use the `react-native run-ios` and it starts up both the simulator and the server but in cases where the app has been installed and you want to restart the server, you can stop it explicitly in the terminal and use `react-native start` or `npm start` to start it up again.

Answer (score 6):

Using `react-native start` when app already installed on device.
Using `react-native run-ios` when we need to install app on device and start the server.
But when we installed new package to our project, we need to restart server using `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use react-native run-android only once at the start of the blank applicaction, and also i run it everytime that i add a component that requires linking.

I use `react-native start` when i am editing the code, i combine it with the DevSettings /Debug server host & port for device where i set my `pc_ip:8081` and that way i can update code on the fly without having to connect my real device to the pc .