# Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions - React-Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I facing this issues while making release Build apk in react native.

check screenshot - https://prnt.sc/sro8ua

> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED w: Detected multiple Kotlin
>   daemon sessions at build\Kotlin\sessions

Please help me anyone facing the same issues.

Answer (score 17):

It could be a lot of reasaons, I fixed it by:

step 1. go to ur_project/android/gradle.properties add the line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

step 2. go to ur_project/android/app/build.gradle, inside android{  .... } add

```
dexOptions {
   incremental true
   javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: where to put the first line inside gradle..??

Comment: ur_project/android/gradle.properties

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes just delete Build folders and retry.
In my case, this problem happen after upgrade the RN version, so cleaning the builds folders, has solved.

Answer (score 1):

**it's works for me**

**step1.** cd android && ./gradlew clean
**step2.** cd ..
step3. npx react-native start

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Error Message: Failed to connect to the package server

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992138/4315172

```
npx react-native start &
```

npx if you have the package not installed yet.

Use the & sign if you want to start it in the background for linux console.
https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/and-ampersand-and-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Enter the /android/gradle.properties file and add the following code

```
    org.gradle.daemon=true
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    org.gradle.parallel=true
    org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Answer (score 0):

these steps work for me

- `adb uninstall "package name"` (Optional)
- `cd android ./gradlew clean`
- `./gradlew -stop`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this error occurs when your Device is not connected properly