# how to use createStackNavigator correctly in react native

Tags: react-native, navigator

I'm learning react native navigation from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation

This is my package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "ReactNativeNavigation",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

This is App.js:

Just copied the code

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run "react-native run-android",it doesn't work properly.

The screenshots is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoTEC.png)

And error info in command prompt is:

```html
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-screens:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-screens
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-screens:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-screens
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.1/gradle-3.3.1.pom'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s

    at makeError (E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

(I paste the code into "Code Snippet" in order to keep the code display normal,I used the stackovflow the first time)

What should I do to solve these problems?

In fact,the demo below is still not working:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>{/* Rest of your app code */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

When I comment out this line of code "import 'react-native-gesture-handler';" 
It works!

I sincerely look forward to your help!

Comment: Check your internet connection. You may install this library using the private network. Try install react-native-screen library in public network.

Comment: Hi.I have solved the problem.The error has nothing to do with the network,but I try to solve problems from the network.This finally solved my problem,although my mistakes were very stupid.If you're interested, check out my answers.

Answer (score 0):

I run the project in android studio,but it display the error info

**"Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again"**

so I do the following:

1.click File->Invalidate Caches/Restart in android studio

2.edit C:\Users\your user name.gradle\gradle.properties

```js
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Mon Jun 08 10:57:14 GMT+08:00 2020
# systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
# systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
# systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
# systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
```

I Comment out the the last four lines codes;

3.wait the Gradle installed

4.close android studio

5.run:react-native run-andriod

the result is:

```html
E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation>react-native run-build
error Unrecognized command "run-build".
info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.

E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1103 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
60 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 57 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory 'E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\appcompat' after 10 attempts

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Unable to delete directory 'E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\appcompat' after 10 attempts

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s

    at makeError (E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)

E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation>
```

Finally,I open a command prompt and input:

**react-native start**

It works！

[image]

I encountered a lot of other mistakes in the process of solving the problem like 
**"Couldn't delete E:\learn\ReactNative\ReactNativeNavigation\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output.json"**
So I delete the file ,but I think this operation is useless.

another error is

**"Android Studio AVD - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1"**

and so on.

At last, I want to know what it did when "react-native start" run.

[When should I run `react-native start`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991717/when-should-i-run-react-native-start)

I was still confused after reading it.

Thanks for Ravi reply.

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: Great to go ahead.

Comment: I find that when I install a new module,"react-native start"is necessary.

Comment: react-native start means, it will start metro bundler that's it. it will auto start when run react-native run-android